# removing selected lists based on a condition

Tags: r

I have a large list which is too big to put here but I am working on making a reproducible output.

The dimensions of the list are the following:

```
> dim(mylist[[70]])
[1] 618   3
> dim(mylist[[71]])
NULL
> dim(mylist[[72]])
[1] 792   3
> dim(mylist[[73]])
[1] 831   3
> dim(mylist[[74]])
[1] 550   3
```

The list is a large list of data frames. However some of the data frames failed to be created correctly. What I am trying to do is to eliminate the list of data frames which have NULL as their dimensions. A screen shot of the list of data frames is here.

[image]

If you can think of a better way to remove these data frames then I am open to this also. I thought about removing all lists whose `Type == Logical`

Comment: Try  `i1 <- lengths(mylist) > 0l; mylist[i1]` or `Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(x) && nrow(x) > 0, mylist)`

Comment: `purrr::keep(mylist, ~ typeof(.x) != "logical")`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan  if it was NULL, then it would be, but, I guess it is `NA`, `dim(NA)` returns NULL. `i <- lengths(mylist)` would also be incorrect as `NA` is having length 1

Comment: @akrun, the first suggestion didnt work for some reason but your second suggeston `Filter(function….` worked great! @JasonAizkalns your suggestion worked also. Thanks again! @IceCreamToucan this method returned a list of 0 but thanks for the suggestion anyways!

Comment: Yes, after I commented I realized there is length of 1 with NA.

Comment: Yep, I just tried it with replacing `> 0` with `> 1` and it worked!

Comment: but, that would create some bugs, when you have a data.frame with row 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to check whether it is a `data.frame` (`is.data.frame`) and if that is TRUE, then check the number of rows to be greater than 0 in `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(x) && nrow(x) > 0, mylist)
```